# For $X ∼ Pois(λ)$, find $E(2^X)$, if it is finite.

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

For $X \sim Pois(λ)$, find $\Bbb E(2^X)$, if it is finite.

Hint: Use these facts, $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}&=e^\lambda\\\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)\lambda^k}{k!}&=e^\lambda+\lambda e^\lambda\end{align}$$

- The lecture ended before we had time to cover this section and I have no notes to work from. I am having trouble getting to the answer because I am getting confused with my work. Any help would be much appreciated.
- I have this so far but I am not sure if it is correct,
  $P(X = x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$ for $x \in\{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E(2^X) &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} 2^x \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}\\&= e^{-\lambda} \mathbb\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2\lambda)^x}{x!}\\&= e^{-\lambda} e^{2\lambda}\end{align}$$
So then $\Bbb E (2^X) = e^\lambda$

Comment: You should use the fact that $$\mathbb{E}\big(f(X)\big)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k)P(X=k)$$ Here $f(x)=2^x$

Comment: @MatthewHolder I am actually not sure whether I can or can't.

Comment: If you can't, I would suggest that you set $Y=2^X$. Notice that the possible outcomes of $Y$ belong to the set $S= \{1,2,2^2,2^3,\ldots\}$. Moreover, for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ you have $$P(Y=2^k)=P(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$ Lastly, $$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\sum_{y\in S}yP(Y=y)$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: @MatthewHolder do you think this could work?                                                                   P(X = x) = $\frac{e^{-λ}λ^x}{x!}$ for x = 0, 1, 2, ...                                                                 $E(2^x) = $$\mathbb\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}$$ 2^x \frac{e^{-λ}λ^x}{x!}$                                   = $e^{-λ} $$\mathbb\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}$$ \frac{2λ^x}{x!}$                                                 = $e^{-λ} e^{2λ}$                                                                                                                   So then $E (2^x) = e^λ$

Comment: Just make sure you write $(2\lambda)^x$ instead of $2\lambda^x$, but that looks good. Note what you did is exactly what I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: @MatthewHolder  yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\operatorname E(2^X) = {} & \sum_{x=0}^\infty 2^x \Pr(X=x) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty 2^x \cdot\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(2\lambda)^x}{x!} \\
& \text{The factor $e^{-\lambda}$ can be pulled out of} \\
& \text{the sum because it does not change} \\
& \text{as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-\lambda} \cdot e^{2\lambda} = e^{\lambda}.
\end{align}

Comment: That should be $\frac{(2\lambda)^x}{x!}$ in the second step.