# Calculating the Variance of $a^x, a \in R$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

*Please give me a hint/direction and not a full answer, as those are my homeworks*

I have a question where $X \sim Po(3)$ and i need to calculate: $Var[2^X]$.

What i tried:

$$
2^x = e^{\ln 2^x} = e^{x\ln 2} \Rightarrow V[2^x] = V[e^{x\ln 2}]
$$

On the other hand, i know that $X \sim Po$ and i know that the $Var$ of a poisson distribution equalls $\lambda$ so i think i should use it somehow but I'm not sure how.

Here im stuck, i know its not much but i dont have an idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Related question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898402/for-x-%e2%88%bc-pois%ce%bb-find-e2x-if-it-is-finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898402/for-x-%E2%88%BC-pois%CE%BB-find-e2x-if-it-is-finite), the expectation is easy to compute.  The expectation of the square is also easy, since $$\operatorname{E}[(2^X)^2] = \operatorname{E}[4^X].$$  Therefore, $$\operatorname{Var}[2^X] = \operatorname{E}[4^X] - \operatorname{E}[2^X]$$ and use the answer provided in the link.

Comment: Solved, thank you and all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MGF of poisson distribution: $M_X(t)=\Bbb E[(e^t)^X]\implies V[e^{X\ln 2}]=\Bbb E[e^{X\ln4}]-\Bbb E[e^{X\ln2}]^2=M_X(\ln 4)-M_X(\ln2)^2$